# Augmenting Object object with a function that all objects can use

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

My motivation for the augmentation of Object is I want to be able to easily handle objects meant to simply store data (like a "hashmap" in Java). I want to easily do hashmap.size().

Let's say my object has a property called objData which was empty when made like this:

```
var objData = {};
```

My object has some methods that can add data to objData like this:

```
this.objData[key1name] = data1;
```

And my object also has some methods which access objData:

```
if(this.objData.size() == 0):
```

Of course, no such method exists. So that's my motivation for augmenting the Object object:

```
        Object.prototype.getOwnPropertyCount = function ( ) {
            var count = 0;
            for(var item in this) {
                if (this.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
            return count;
        };
```

Now I should be able to do either:

```
if (this.objData.getOwnPropertyCount() == 0)
```

or:

```
if(!objData.getOwnPropertyCount())
```

But in actuality I get errors when I try to load the page completely unrelated to any code I've written. I'm getting errors thrown in google maps api's main.js. Voodoo.

So I change my augmentation to augment the actual Object instead of Object.prototype:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyCount = function ( ) {
    //calculate the count
    return count;
};
```

And now I get the following error in Firefox:

```
this.objData.getOwnPropertyCount is not a function
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move your method declaration from `Object.prototype` directly to the `Object` constructor, the method is no longer available in the prototype chain of all objects (a good thing BTW), I would suggest you to provide your function an argument, to pass the object you need to opearate, and change your method call:

```
// from `this.objData.getOwnPropertyCount()` to:
Object.getOwnPropertyCount(this.objData);
```

And obviously, in your implementation, you should count the properties of the passed object, since `this`, will refer to the `Object` constuctor, in the above example.

Comment: right. thanks. I read the "beget" definition that Crockford did when he augmented Object, but I forgot to check how he actually used it :p

Comment: but why does augmenting Object.Prototype fail?

Comment: @highwind7777, it could be a due a lot of things, I cannot tell you without looking at your page, usually, some script using the `for-in` statement, without ensuring that the properties are *own*, another common thing, using the `for-in` statement to *"iterate"* Array objects...